# Postgres table partitioning with Rails errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Our system currently uses Postgresql 9.6 with Rails but has been having table performance problems. We decided to add table partitioning and I created the triggers to do that. My problem is that `CREATE` works perfectly, but `INSERT` and `UPDATE` gives me constraint errors. Has anyone had good luck in implementing this? I would also note that I added a `DELETE` trigger for removing the row from parent after insert, but that gives me problems in tests because it can't find the row. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Example of error:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "table2" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_647be12f23"
         DETAIL:  Key (id)=(7867) is not present in table "table1".
```

Comment: Can you add a _describe_ of your tables and the migrations (if any)?